# Tensorflow DQN can't solve OpenAI Cartpole

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openal, openai-gym

I've been learning tensorflow and rl for months, and for the past few days I've been trying to solve *OpenAI* *Cartpole* with my own code but my *Deep Q-Network* can't seem to solve it. I've checked and compared my code to other implementations and I don't see where I am going wrong? Can anyone look over my implementation and *teach me what I am messing up?* It would mean a lot, thanks.

My code:

```html
import gym
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import math
import keras
import random

class cartpole:
    def __init__(self, sess, env):
        self.env = env
        self.state_size = env.observation_space.shape[0]
        self.num_actions = env.action_space.n
        self.sess = sess
        self.epsilon = 1.0
        self.return_loss = 0.0
        self.memory = []
        self.gamma = .95

        self.q_model()
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        self.sess.run(init)
    
    def q_model(self):
        self.state_input = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, self.state_size], dtype=tf.float32)
        self.reward_labels = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 1], dtype=tf.float32)

        self.hiddenlayer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.state_size, 32]))
        self.hiddenlayer1_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32]))
        self.hiddenlayer1_output = tf.matmul(self.state_input, self.hiddenlayer1_weights) + self.hiddenlayer1_bias
        self.hiddenlayer1_output = tf.nn.relu(self.hiddenlayer1_output)

        self.hiddenlayer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32, 16]))
        self.hiddenlayer2_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16]))
        self.hiddenlayer2_output = tf.matmul(self.hiddenlayer1_output, self.hiddenlayer2_weights) + self.hiddenlayer2_bias
        self.hiddenlayer2_output = tf.nn.relu(self.hiddenlayer2_output)


        self.q_weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16, self.num_actions]))
        self.q_bias = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.num_actions]))
        self.q_output = tf.matmul(self.hiddenlayer2_output, self.q_weights) + self.q_bias
        self.q_output = keras.activations.linear(self.q_output)
        
        
        self.max_q_value = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_max(self.q_output), (1,1))
        self.best_action = tf.squeeze(tf.argmax(self.q_output, axis=1))

        self.loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(self.max_q_value, self.reward_labels)
        self.train_model = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(self.loss)
    
    def predict_action(self, state):
        self.epsilon *= .995 + .01
        if (np.random.random() < self.epsilon):
            action = env.action_space.sample()
        else:
            action = self.sess.run(self.best_action, feed_dict={self.state_input: state})
        return action

    def predict_value(self, state):
        state = np.array(state).reshape((1, 4))
        max_q_value = self.sess.run(self.max_q_value, feed_dict={self.state_input: state})[0][0]
        return max_q_value

    
    def train_q_model(self, state, reward):
        q_values, _, loss = self.sess.run([self.q_output, self.train_model, self.loss], feed_dict={self.state_input: state, self.reward_labels: reward})
        self.return_loss = loss

    def get_loss(self):
        return self.return_loss

    def experience_replay(self):
        if len(self.memory) < 33:
            return
        del self.memory[0]
        batch = random.sample(self.memory, 32)
        for state, action, reward, new_state, done in self.memory:
            reward = reward if not done else - reward
            new_state = np.array(new_state).reshape((1, 4))
            if not done:
                reward = reward + (self.gamma * self.predict_value(new_state)) 
            reward = np.array(reward).reshape((1, 1))
            
            self.train_q_model(state, reward)



env = gym.make("CartPole-v0")
sess = tf.Session()
A2C = cartpole(sess, env)

episodes = 2000
reward_history = []
for i in range(episodes):
    state = env.reset()
    reward_total = 0
    while True:
        state = np.array(state).reshape((1, 4))
        average_best_reward = sum(reward_history[-100:]) / 100.0
        if (average_best_reward) > 195:
            env.render()

        action = A2C.predict_action(state)
        new_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
        reward_total += reward
        A2C.memory.append([state, action, reward, new_state, done])
        A2C.experience_replay()
        state = new_state


        if done:
            if (average_best_reward >= 195):
                print("Finished! Episodes taken: ", i, "average reward: ", average_best_reward)
            print("average reward  = ", average_best_reward, "reward total = ", reward_total, "loss = ", A2C.get_loss())
            reward_history.append(reward_total)
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial epsilon is set to 1 `self.epsilon = 1.0`. And yet, when you perform an action, instead of decaying it, you increase it.

```
self.epsilon *= .995 + .01
```

*1.0 x 0.995 + 0.01 = 0.995 + 0.01 = 1.005*

The exploration factor (epsilon) should be **decayed**:

```
self.epsilon *= .995
```

This causes the agent to never use your trained network and instead sticks to performing random actions.

Also, updating the exploration factor right before `return action` would be optimal, since you want it to use the initial epsilon for the first action as well.

```
def predict_action(self, state):
    if (np.random.random() < self.epsilon):
        action = env.action_space.sample()
    else:
        action = self.sess.run(self.best_action, feed_dict={self.state_input: state})
    self.epsilon *= .995
    return action
```

You can also change `if len(self.memory) < 33:` to `if len(self.memory) < 32:`, assuming you want 32 to be your batch size.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the correct points mentioned already, you are importing both Tensorflow as well as `Keras`. However, the only time you leverage `Keras` is with `keras.activations.linear`. everything else you do is done using `Tensorflow` directly.

Keras is a framwork built on top of Tensorflow, which simplifies the usage of the underlying Tensorflow libraries. I suggest you look some more into the differences of them and try to implement the above code using Keras only. While you already know how to do this in TF, you will appreciate the simplicity Keras will bring.

A simple help is would be this Cartpole agent from the OpenAI Leaderboard:
https://gym.openai.com/evaluations/eval_GazXePIETsOvUaxmoILNHw/